# Spring AfterReturningAdvice firing before transaction commits

Tags: wcf, spring, nhibernate, spring.net, spring-aop

I seem to be having a weird problem. In our services layer, we are using WCF with nHibernate and Spring.NET 1.3.0.20349. I don't have the option to upgrade spring to the next version.

I have save methods on a service that has AfterReturningAdvices which are required to make another service call that calls into the Db and uses the ID of the saved object.  **The problem is that the interceptor is firing before the transaction commits which is causing the next service call to return empty objects**

After some reading, my understanding of Springs Interceptors are :

1. The pre-interceptors beforeadvice methods run
2. Spring starts the transaction
3. The post-interceptors beforeadvice methods run
4. The main service method runs
5. The post-interceptors afterreturning advice methods run
6. Spring commits the transaction
7. The pre-interceptors afterreturning advice methods run

My web.config has the following:

```
  <object id="InsertPointcut" type="Spring.Aop.Support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="advice">
      <ref local="afterAddInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="MappedNames">
      <list>
        <value>AddToEvent</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="UpdatePointcut" type="Spring.Aop.Support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="advice">
      <ref local="afterUpdateInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="MappedNames">
      <list>
        <value>Update</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>
      <object id="ServiceProxy" type="Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryObject, Spring.Data">
    <property name="PlatformTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="TransactionAttributeSource" ref="attributeTransactionAttributeSource"/>
    <property name="target">
      <object id="Service" type="Service, Service" init-method="init">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="EventRepository" ref="eventRepository" />
      </object>
    </property>
    <property name="preInterceptors">
      <list>
        <ref local="throwsAdvice"/>
        <ref local="InsertPointcut"/>
        <ref local="UpdatePointcut"/>
      </list>
    </property>       
  </object>
```

Can anyone help?

**[Update]**

In order to avoid making code changes to my services, I implemented the *ITransactionSynchronization* interface on my advice and registered it. That way, in the AfterCompletion method, I can do my work after spring & nHibernate has committed. I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle this but it seems to work.

```
 public class AfterUpdateInterceptor : IAfterReturningAdvice, ITransactionSynchronization
{
    private int id;
    [Transaction]
    public void AfterReturning(object returnValue, MethodInfo method, object[] args, object target)
    {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.RegisterSynchronization(this);
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        id = PropertyHelper.GetIdPropertyValue<IUpdateContract>(args);
    }

    public void Suspend()
    {
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
    }

    public void BeforeCommit(bool readOnly)
    {
    }

    public void AfterCommit()
    {
    }

    public void BeforeCompletion()
    {
    }

    public void AfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationStatus status)
    {
        if (status != TransactionSynchronizationStatus.Committed) return;//.com msg not sent.

        if (id > 0)
        {
            XmlSender.SendXmlUpdate(MessageType.Update, id);
        }
        id = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source of the [TransactionProxyFactoryObject](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~br=master/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Data/Transaction/Interceptor/TransactionProxyFactoryObject.cs?r=0e3f54715361e930bceaa1eb3f322609da19116f)'s `AfterPropertySet` Method, I think that is in fact the order of the applied advices. So you should have a  AfterReturningAdvice configured in your pre-interceptors. 
If this isn't called, it might be a bug and I would suggest to ask in the [spring.net forums](http://forum.springframework.net/).

Another way to get called when an transaction is comitted is the [ITransactionSynchronization](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#d4e5512) Interface which can be registered with the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`.

Comment: The advice is getting called, but it seems to be getting called too early (before commit). I will look into using the TransactionSynchronizationManager